# How to grant an aws lambda permission to send messages to a specific SQS using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-sqs

I want to grant a lambda permission to access a specific queue using the AWS cli so i am able to send messages to that queue from the lambda.

So for example if i want to add sqs:SendMessage to a lambda so it can send messages to a queue resource using the AWS CLI, what is the command to do that?

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function in the same AWS Account as the Amazon SQS queue? If so, you should simply add the appropriate permissions to the IAM Role that is assigned to the Lambda function. This is best done via the IAM Management Console, since there is probably an existing IAM Role used with the Lambda function.

Comment: Here is the AWS document on modifying a role:- [Modifying a role permissions policy (AWS CLI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-managingrole-editing-cli.html#roles-modify_permissions-policy-cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have to add an IAM policy to your lambda role. the policy can be something like below.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:SendMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

add the ARN of your SQS resource in Resource Property.